# Sublime Text 2 Mac Removing Folders on Close

Tags: sublimetext2

I use Sublime text 2 as my IDE at both work and home. On a windows machine sublime remembers all the folders in the left had column when the programme is closed ect.

However on my mac using sublime removes the folders as soon as that window is closed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What about mailing the Sublime text authors? After all, it's a paid product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option should be under  Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings – Default

[image]

```
// Exiting the application with hot_exit enabled will cause it to close
// immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
// be preserved and restored when next starting.
//
// Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
// without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
// alongside the project.
"hot_exit": false,

// remember_open_files makes the application start up with the last set of
// open files. Changing this to false will have no effect if hot_exit is
// true
"remember_open_files": false,
```

Comment: That sorted it. Thanks :)